# Array prototype available in forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have a polyfill for `Array.find()` that I got from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

The browser I'm currently testing in doesn't have support for it so the polyfill runs and functions as intended. However a plugin I have is `foreach` over an array I pass it and the last element in that is the function `find`.

Why is this happening?

Also when I inspect the array in Chrome's DevTools I get the following.

```js
if (!Array.find) {
   $('<h5>This browser doesnt support Array.find</h5>').appendTo('body');
}

if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}

var someArray = [{name: 'something'}, {name: 'something else'}];

someArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
  $('<h4>'+ item.name +'</h4>').appendTo('body');
});

var extended = $.extend({}, [], someArray);

$.each(extended, function (index, item) { 
  $('<h4>'+ item.name +'</h4>').appendTo('body');
});

if (extended.find) {
  $("<div>Notice that we now have in extended the function find<div>").appendTo('body');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Notice that `find` in the `__proto__` is a darker shade of pink than the other `proto`'s.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: What browser is this happening in, and can you provide the code block where this happening?

Comment: Are you doing a `for..in` over an array?  You shouldn't do that (at least not without a `.hasOwnProperty()` call).

Comment: This is happening in a plugin not with my code. I know how to fix it was just curious why it happened with his code. Looks like his jq `extend` is adding `find` to the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `foreach` extension is checking keys but not checking that they are own-properties of the object. That is, this code:

```
Array.prototype.x = 3;
var test = [1];
for (var key in test) {
    console.log(key); 
}
```

...will log both `0` and `x` because `x` is an enumerable key in `[]` which is not an own-property of `[]`. To fix this you can either patch the `foreach` code to check for own-properties only:

```
Array.prototype.x = 3;
var test = [1];
for (var key in test) {
    if (test.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key); 
    }
}
```

Or you can change the way that you put the key on the prototype, so that like the other keys on the prototype, it is not enumerable. The revised poyfill would be:

```
(function () { // scope bracket; hides `find` from global scope.
    function find(predicate) {
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
        }
        if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
        }
        var list = Object(this), length = list.length >>> 0, thisArg = arguments[1], value, i;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            value = list[i];
            if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
                    return value;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    };
    if (!Array.prototype.find) {
        if (Object.defineProperty) {
            Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {value: find, enumerable: false});
        } else {
            Array.prototype.find = find;
        }
    }
} ());
```

If your browser does not support `Array.prototype.find`, however, there is a chance that it does not support `Object.defineProperty`, leaving you back in the same place as before. Then you will need to hope that it is not so old that it lacks `.hasOwnProperty()` testing, and you'll need to modify the `foreach` function. (The `Array.prototype.find()` function is part of the ECMAScript 6 draft; `Object.defineProperty()` was standardized in ECMAScript 5.1, while `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` is ECMAScript 3. ES5.1 was released in 2011 so as long as your browser is only a couple years old, the above should work for you -- in particular if you're using a current Opera or IE, those don't have the new ES6 `.find()` in them yet, but they have `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Bingo Bango Bongo. You sir have won the internet for me with that revised polyfill. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome darkens the methods added to it but not already a part of it.

**Do this**

```
Array.prototype.hi  = function() {}
```

And then do

```
console.log(Array.prototype);
```

You'll see `hi` is darkened. Since `find` was not already a part of `Array.prototype`, but became one after executing your code, it is darkened, the same way `hi` is darkened.